# js callback function

Tags: javascript

How can I callback to a function in an object?

```
json_post('get_tracks', 'json.request.php?get=tracks', 'genreId='+id+'&perPage=70&page=1', 'rtn_tracks');
```

Instead of making a callback to rtn_tracks() I want to do it to this.rtn()

How can I define this in the callback string?

Here is the code:

```
function stream_tracks(){
 this.get = function(id){
  json_post('get_tracks', 'json.request.php?get=tracks', 'genreId='+id+'&perPage=70&page=1', 'rtn_tracks');
 };

 this.rtn = function(json_obj){
  this.cnstr(json_obj);
 };

 this.cnstr = function(json_obj){
  alert('test');
 };
}
Stream_tracks = new stream_tracks();

var XMLHTTP = {};
function json_post(request_uid, uri, get_str, callback_function, callback_var){
 request_uid += Math.floor(Math.random()*999999).toString();

 if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
  XMLHTTP[request_uid] = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else if(window.ActiveXObject){
  XMLHTTP[request_uid] = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
 }

 XMLHTTP[request_uid].open('POST', uri, true);
 XMLHTTP[request_uid].setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 XMLHTTP[request_uid].onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(XMLHTTP[request_uid].readyState == 4){
   if(callback_function){
    eval(callback_function+'('+XMLHTTP[request_uid].responseText+(callback_var ? ', callback_var':'')+')');
   }
  }
 }
 XMLHTTP[request_uid].send(get_str);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: please select your code snippets and click on "code sample" (ctrl+k) button ;)

Comment: In the texteditor, select the code snippet and press the "{}" button. If your code is not formatted to begin with, run it through here http://jsbeautifier.org/ e.g..

Comment: I've edited it for you, but as polarblau said.

Comment: @user555222 - If you are going to use a resource at least learn to use it properly. There are ten buttons you'll need to learn with helpful tool tips that describe what they do. You could also click the rather large question mark to get a detailed manual on how to use the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass functions as objects in Javascript, you don't need to pass the function name and use eval. If your callback should be called as a member of a class, you need to pass along the class instance as well. E.g. add a callback context argument to your json function:

```
function json_post(request_uid, uri, get_str, callback_function, callback_var, callback_context){
    /*... snip ...*/
    XMLHTTP[request_uid].onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(XMLHTTP[request_uid].readyState == 4)
        {
            if(callback_function){
                /* The call() function lets you call a function in a context */
                callback_function.call(
                    callback_context || this,
                    XMLHTTP[request_uid].responseText, 
                    callback_var
                );
            }
        }
    };
    XMLHTTP[request_uid].send(get_str);
}
```

Then you would call it like so:

```
json_post('get_tracks', 'json.request.php?get=tracks', 'genreId='+id+'&perPage=70&page=1', 
    this.rtn, // callback function
    null, // callback var
    this // callback context
);
```

Here's a good tip though: Use a framework! It will make your day a lot easier.

Comment: I get this: callback_function.call is not a function

Comment: btw. how would you structure this code by using a framework? :)

Comment: @user555222 If you get "callback_function.call is not a function", then callback_function is not a function :-) Are you sure you are passing `this.rtn` as the callback_function argument, and not "this.rtn" or "rtn" etc?

Comment: With a framework you could skip all the XMLHTTP mess, you could bind the callback to the instance (so you wouldn't have to pass a context object) etc. It's just more convenient.

Comment: could you give me an example of what you mean about that framework?

Comment: For example, using jQuery, you can do a request to the server with `jQuery.get("/json.request.php", 'get=tracks&genreId='+id+'&perPage=70&page=1', myCallback);` , you don't have to worry about browser discrepancies, readyStates etc. I'm not saying you MUST use a framework, just that it makes your life easier, in most cases.

Comment: I have now tried to make a framework the best I could, but now I experience another "strange" problem around line 10.. this is somehow overwritten and when trying calling this.cnstr() it returns undefined.. alerting this and the window object is returned!? http://temp.electrobeat.dk/json.js

Comment: another ting.. now when I'm not using eval() in my json post function the result is returned as a string.. how can I convert it into an object?

Comment: @user555222 When `Stream_tracks.rtn` is called as a callback, it doesn't know that it is a member of the `Stream_tracks` class. That's why you have to pass along a context and use `callback_function.call(context, arg1, arg2...)`..

Comment: It's a little difficult to explain it in this small text field, I recommend that you go through http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/ . Regarding your second question: the result is always returned as a string. To make it a javascript object, you need to parse the string. You _can_ do that with eval, but it's safer to use a dedicated JSON parser (had you used a framework, it would probably have one ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a string for callback, use a method.

```
var my = {
    start : function (s, callback) {
        callback(s);
    },
    callback: function(s) {
    }
}
```

You cannot use:

```
my.start("Hello World", my.callback)
```

Since this will cause the method to be processed without connection to the object my but you can do this.

```
my.start("Hello World", function(s) { my.callback(s); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are a couple of things that you need to do and it might make more sense if you have a read about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Firstly you'll need to make a reference to the `this` variable so you can access it inside your callback without overwritting it.

```
function stream_tracks(){
   var obj = this;
```

Then if you want to refer to properties of that class/object from within its other methods you just use `obj.this`.

The second thing you should do is pass the callback as a function not as a string. It will also be more efficient as you will be able to do away with the eval function.

```
 this.get = function(id){
  json_post(
       'get_tracks',
       'json.request.php?get=tracks',
       'genreId='+id+'&perPage=70&page=1',
       function(){ obj.rtn(); }
     );
 };
```

Wrapping the callback in the anonymous function forms the closure and allows the function to use the variables from class. Also if you do it this way you can pass any parameters through at the same time as the function and do away with the extra parameters in the parent function.